# How to get the entire content of a variable in the debug watch window of visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

[image]

If i right click and copy i only get half text:

```
-       text    0x00000000000f20d0 L"_BinRun.IMAGE_DOS_HEADER := \"\t\tWORD   e_magic;\n\t\tWORD   e_cblp;\n\t\tWORD   e_cp;\n\t\tWORD   e_crlc;\n\t\tWORD   e_cparhdr;\n\t\tWORD   e_minalloc;\n\t\tWORD   e_maxalloc;\n\t\tWORD   e_ss;\n\t\tWORD   e_sp;\n\t\tWORD   e_c...  wchar_t *
```

[image]

Trying to get the entire content as a literal string including `\"\t\t\n\` etc.
Im using c++ in my project and vstudio2019.

Comment: One slightly messy way is to display the variable in a Memory window.  Enter the address of the variable to do this.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: Open a memory window if necessary via Menu -> Debug -> Windows -> Memory -> Memory 1.  Then type `&your_variable_name` in the Address box.  You need to do this with the program paused.

Comment: Can you edit your question to clarify your intent? What exactly are you trying to do with the string? The only thing the debugger is designed to do is display the content. When you copy the string via the String Visualizer it includes the all white space such as the tabs and newlines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. The string is too long to display directly in the debugger watch window. Use the String Visualizer by clicking the magnifying glass to the right of the variable. [That's what it's for](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/string-visualizer-dialog-box?view=vs-2019) and then copy it from there:

(Emphasis mine)

> While you are debugging in Visual Studio, you can view strings with the built-in string visualizer. The string visualizer shows strings that are **too long for a data tip or debugger window**.

Comment: I know about the string visualizer but i would like to get the content as a literal string including `\"\t\t\n\` etc

Comment: String Visualizer also doesn't always show the full contents. :(