# How to print the content of a string as "sting literal source"

Tags: c++

Suppose `s` is

```
a
b
c
```

```cpp
    const std::string s = 
    std::cout << R"( s )" << std::endl;
```

How to `std::cout` the content of the string in raw literal? I mean the `cout` return the value in this format: `"a\nb\nc"`.

I need to transform a very large text into a `std::string`.
I cant use fileread as i need to define its value inside the src.

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435667/print-string-without-escaping-characters

Comment: Try using the memory view window (paste the address) you can page-down until you run out of your address space.

Comment: You literally just posted this question yesterday. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66484391/how-to-get-the-entire-content-of-a-variable-in-the-debug-watch-window-of-visual

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the entire content of a variable in the debug watch window of visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66484391/how-to-get-the-entire-content-of-a-variable-in-the-debug-watch-window-of-visual)

Comment: Your title is very misleading. What you want is a text where escape sequences are printed as escape sequences instead of expanding. To achieve that, you'd have to replace characters in question (carriage retrurn, tab, etc) with the escape sequences.

Comment: Your attempt to use a raw string literal goes against the intended use of a raw string literal. A raw string literal is exactly the characters within the parentheses *with no substitutions* (a space followed by the character `'s'` followed by a space, in your example). Your second phrasing of your question, where you state you want to see a backslash followed by the character `'n'`, is more accurate.

Comment: @Richard Critten but on the memory window its not as raw literal https://i.imgur.com/YZ9GW9C.png

Comment: Please refrain from calling it 'raw literal', as this term has a meaning in C++, and that meaning doesn't apply to your goal.

Comment: How to call it then?

Comment: @Frank: There's no term for "I want to print the C++ escape codes/values for the control codes in a string". So it's just best to spell that out.

Comment: @Frank You could try coining the phrase "sting literal source", but you might still need to explain what you mean (the string literal as it exists in a source file, rather than the form seen in the compilation [phase of translation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases)). It might be better to go with something more like "string with escape sequences", keeping the example.

Comment: @JaMiT i have add more information to the topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load this text file into a `std::string` like this:

Store the text in your file, e.g. mystring.txt, as a raw string literal in the format `R"(raw_characters)"`:

```
R"(Run.M128A XmmRegisters[16];
          BYTE Reserved4[96];", Run.CONTEXT64 := "        DWORD64 P1Home;
          DWORD64 P2Home;
...
)"
```

#include the file into a string:

```
namespace
{
    const std::string mystring =
    #include "mystring.txt"
    ;
}
```

Your IDE might flag this up as a syntax error, but it isn't. What you're doing is loading the contents of file directly into the string at compile time.

Finally print the string:

```
std::cout << mystring << std::endl;
```

**Why not just save the escaped version of the string in the file?**

---

Any way, here's a function to 'escape' characters:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

std::string replace_all(const std::string &mystring)
{
    const std::unordered_map<char, std::string> lookup =
        { {'\n', "\\n"}, {'\t', "\\t"}, {'"', "\\\""} };

    std::string new_string;
    new_string.reserve(mystring.length() * 2);

    for (auto c : mystring)
    {
        auto it = lookup.find(c);
        if (it != lookup.end())
            new_string += it->second;
        else
            new_string += c;
    }

    return new_string;
}

int main() {

    std::string mystring = R"(Run.M128A XmmRegisters[16];
          BYTE Reserved4[96];", Run.CONTEXT64 := "        DWORD64 P1Home;
          DWORD64 P2Home;
          DWORD64 P3Home;
          DWORD64 P4Home;
          DWORD64 P5Home;
          DWORD64 P6Home;)";
    auto new_string = replace_all(mystring);
    std::cout << new_string << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nv3eaY).

Comment: @Frank Thtat's your IDE thinking there's syntax error, but what you're doing is including the contents of the file directly to your string. Have you tried compiling?

Comment: Compiled but it does not print it as raw/literal https://i.imgur.com/tmaNoaO.png

Comment: @Frank See my update. Sorry, I didn't realise that you wanted to escape characters. I've used a map to look up the chars to replace. You can add to that as you wish.

Comment: Thank you for your time @jignatius, there's only one problem, the script is not escaping quotes

Comment: I have changed this line adding `"` is it correct? `std::unordered_map<char, std::string> lookup = { {'\"', "\\\""}, {'\n', "\\n"}, {'\t', "\\t"} };`

Comment: @Frank No you need `{'"', "\\\""}`. I've updated the map. Plus made it `const` too.

Answer (score 1):

What you would need to do is to scan the string, and replace all occurrences of the characters you are interested in (such as carriage return, tab, etc) with printable escape sequence and than print this new text.

Here is somewhat crude proof of concept:

```
std::string escape(std::string_view src) {
     std::string ret;
     ret.reserve(src.size() * 2); // at worst, the string consists solely of escapable symbols
    
     static constexpr std::array escapable = {std::make_pair('\t', 't'), 
                                              std::make_pair('\n', 'n')}; // add more chars as needed, note that the array is sorted

     for (const char ch: src) {
         std::pair search_pair{ch, ' '}; 
         auto esc_char = std::equal_range(escapable.begin(), escapable.end(), search_pair, [](auto& a, auto& b) { return a.first < b.first; });
         if (esc_char.first != escapable.end()) {
             ret.push_back('\\');
             ret.push_back(esc_char.first->second);
         } else {
             ret.push_back(ch);
         }
     }
     return ret;
}
```

Now, you can use it:

```
const std::string str = "A\nbub\tfuf\n";

std::cout << escape(str) << "\n";
```

Above snippet prints `A\nbub\tfuf\n`

Comment: Hi Sergey, i got an error in your script: https://i.imgur.com/AT4Fhbq.png

Answer (score 1):

## You could be interested by the [JSON](https://json.org/) specification.

You could consider serializing your data in JSON format using open source C++ libraries like [jsoncpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp)

### You could also consider using some [YAML](https://yaml.org/) format with the [yaml-cpp](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/) library

You could be interested by the [SWIG](https://swig.org/) tool which generates C++ glue code.

You could consider using binary data formats like [XDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation).

**You should specify** (on paper, with a pencil) **your data format in [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBNF) notation** and use [ANTLR](https://antlr.org/) or [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) to generate the parser (the printer is easier to code)

The [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) project (an open source symbolic artificial intelligence system, [GPLv3+](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/quick-guide-gplv3.en.html) licensed) is persisting data in textual format. You may borrow some code are re-use it in your application, if you obey to that GPL license.

Look also into [Qt](https://qt.io/) or [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/) frameworks, but notice that `DWORD64` is *not* a standard C++ type. See [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) and read a recent C++ standard (like [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) or better).

## Consider generating your C++ serializing code

With tools like [GNU m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/) or [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp) (or your own one).

Pitrat's book [*Artificial Beings: the Conscience of a Conscious Machine*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1848211015) (ISBN-13: 978-1848211018) should give you valuable insight and intuitions.